# How do you setup CMake to work with an external library (sqlpp11)?

Tags: c++, mysql, linux, cmake

I have gotten the two libraries necessary for my cpp application.

https://github.com/rbock/sqlpp11
https://github.com/rbock/sqlpp11-connector-mysql

I have them downloaded along with libmysqlclient-dev and the date library. All of the library tests work when I create a build dir in each of the project `cmake ..` and `make` and run `make tests`.

I import both the libraries in the root directory of the project using `import_library()`, and there are no errors with `cmake ..` from the build dir. When I run a `make` the code is unable to find the includes for `<sqlpp11/sqlpp11.h>` even though the `cmake ..` runs ok. The following is my root `CMakeLists.txt` and my src `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(mysql_sample)

set(HinnantDate_ROOT_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/date")

find_library(sqlpp11 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${sqlpp11_INCLUDE_DIRS})

find_library(sqlpp11-connector-mysql REQUIRED)
include_directories(${sqlpp11-connector-mysql_INCLUDE_DIRS})

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

add_subdirectory(include)
add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(test)
```

and

```
add_executable(mysql_sample main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(mysql_sample ${sqlpp11_LIBRARIES}) 
target_link_libraries(mysql_sample ${sqlpp11-connector-mysql_LIBRARIES})
```

**Edit 1**

In response to the comment the error is

```
Maker Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:148 (message):
  Could NOT find Sqlpp11-connector-mysql (missing:
  sqlpp11-connector-mysql_INCLUDE_DIR)
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:388 (_FPHSA_FAILURE_MESSAGE)
  CMake/FindSqlpp11-connector-mysql.cmake:7 (FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS)
  CMakeLists.txt:15 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/andrew/cpp_work/sql_sample_project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/andrew/cpp_work/sql_sample_project/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

With CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(mysql_sample)

set(HinnantDate_ROOT_DIR "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/date")

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake)

find_package(Sqlpp11 REQUIRED)
include_directories(${sqlpp11_INCLUDE_DIRS})

set(include_dir "${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include")
file(GLOB_RECURSE sqlpp_headers ${include_dir}/*.h ${SQLPP11_INCLUDE_DIR}/*.h)
include_directories(${include_dir})

find_package(Sqlpp11-connector-mysql REQUIRED)
include_directories(${sqlpp11-connector-mysql_INCLUDE_DIRS})

file(GLOB_RECURSE sqlpp11-connector-mysql_headers ${include_dir}/*.h ${sqlpp11-connector-mysql_INCLUDE_DIR}/*.h)
include_directories(${include_dir})

add_executable(mysql_sample src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(mysql_sample ${sqlpp11_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(mysql_sample ${sqlpp11-connector-mysql_LIBRARIES})

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

add_subdirectory(include)
add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(test)
```

and FindSqlpp11.cmake

```
find_path(SQLPP11_INCLUDE_DIR sqlpp11.h
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/sqlpp11
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/sqlpp11
)

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(Sqlpp11 DEFAULT_MSG SQLPP11_INCLUDE_DIR)

mark_as_advanced(SQLPP11_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

and FindSqlpp11-connector-mysql.cmake

```
find_path(Sqlpp11-connector-mysql_INCLUDE_DIR sqlpp11-connector-mysql.h
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/sqlpp11-connector-mysql
    ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/sqlpp11-connector-mysql
)

include(FindPackageHandleStandardArgs)
FIND_PACKAGE_HANDLE_STANDARD_ARGS(Sqlpp11-connector-mysql DEFAULT_MSG sqlpp11-connector-mysql_INCLUDE_DIR)

mark_as_advanced(Sqlpp11-connector-mysql_INCLUDE_DIR)
```

Why is there an error here and am I on the right track?

**Edit 2**

I managed to get the above working, my issue was that I was not installing properly. I now get the following error from this code.

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x124): undefined reference to `sqlpp::mysql::connection::connection(std::shared_ptr<sqlpp::mysql::con
nection_config> const&)'                                                                                              
main.cpp:(.text+0x12e): undefined reference to `sqlpp::mysql::connection::~connection()'                              
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status                                                                            
CMakeFiles/mysql_sample.dir/build.make:94: recipe for target 'mysql_sample' failed                                    
make[2]: *** [mysql_sample] Error 1                                                                                   
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/mysql_sample.dir/all' failed                                   
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/mysql_sample.dir/all] Error 2                                                                
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed                                                                           
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Code:

```
include "TabSample.h"
#include <sqlpp11/sqlpp11.h>
#include <sqlpp11/mysql/mysql.h>

namespace mysql = sqlpp::mysql;
int main()
{
    auto config = std::make_shared<mysql::connection_config>();
    config->user = "root";
    config->database = "sqlpp_mysql";
    config->debug = true;
    mysql::connection db(config);

    TabSample tab;
    for(const auto& row : db.run(sqlpp::select(all_of(tab)).from(tab).unconditionally()))
    {
        std::cerr << "row.alpha: " << row.alpha << ", row.beta: " << row.beta << ", row.gamma: " << row.gamma <<  std::endl;
    };
  return 0;
}
```

I am using gcc 4.9 and there are no errors with the make / make install, am I missing something in my CMakeLists.txt?

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(mysql_sample)

set(HinnantDate_ROOT_DIR "/usr/local/lib/date")
include_directories(/usr/local/lib/date)
if(UNIX)
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -std=gnu++0x")
endif()

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake)

set(SQLPP11_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/local/include)

find_package(Sqlpp11 REQUIRED)

add_executable(mysql_sample src/main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(mysql_sample ${sqlpp11_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(mysql_sample ${sqlpp11-connector-mysql_LIBRARIES})

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

add_subdirectory(include)
add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(test)
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(mysql_sample)

set(HinnantDate_ROOT_DIR "/usr/local/lib/date")
include_directories(/usr/local/lib/date)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

if(UNIX)
    SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall")
endif()

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/CMake)

set(SQLPP11_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/local/include)

find_package(Sqlpp11 REQUIRED)

add_executable(mysql_sample src/main.cpp)

include_directories(${sqlpp11_INCLUDE_DIRS})
include_directories(${sqlpp11-connector-mysql_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_link_libraries(mysql_sample ${sqlpp11_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(mysql_sample ${sqlpp11-connector-mysql_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(mysql_sample mysqlclient)

include_directories(${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/include)

add_subdirectory(include)
add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(test)
```

FindSqlpp11-connector-mysql.cmake

```
## -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
## Check for the library

find_library (sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql_LIBRARIES sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql
  PATHS usr/local/cmake /usr/local/cmake/sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /lib /sw/lib /usr/local/include
  )

## -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
## Actions taken when all components have been found

if (sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql_INCLUDES AND sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql_LIBRARIES)
  set (HAVE_sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql TRUE)
else (sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql_INCLUDES AND sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql_LIBRARIES)
  if (NOT sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql_FIND_QUIETLY)
    if (NOT sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql_INCLUDES)
      message (STATUS "Unable to find sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql header files!")
    endif (NOT sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql_INCLUDES)
    if (NOT sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql_LIBRARIES)
      message (STATUS "Unable to find sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql library files!")
    endif (NOT sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql_LIBRARIES)
  endif (NOT sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql_FIND_QUIETLY)
endif (sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql_INCLUDES AND sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql_LIBRARIES)

if (HAVE_sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql)
  if (NOT sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql_FIND_QUIETLY)
    message (STATUS "Found components for sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql")
    message (STATUS "sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql_INCLUDES = ${sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql_INCLUDES}")
    message (STATUS "sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql_LIBRARIES     = ${sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql_LIBRARIES}")
  endif (NOT sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql_FIND_QUIETLY)
else (HAVE_sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql)
  if (sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql_FIND_REQUIRED)
    message (FATAL_ERROR "Could not find sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql!")
  endif (sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql_FIND_REQUIRED)
endif (HAVE_sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql)

mark_as_advanced (
  HAVE_sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql
  sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql_LIBRARIES
  sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql_INCLUDES
)
```

and the error output:

```
root@beaglebone:~/cpp_work/sql_sample_project/build# cmake ..     
-- Attempting to find SQLPP11 FILES                               
-- Unable to find SQLPP11 library files!                          
-- Unable to find sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql header files!     
-- Unable to find sqlpp11-connector-mysql-mysql library files!    
-- Configuring done                                               
-- Generating done
```

Comment: [find_library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/find_library.html) is not the same as [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/find_package.html): While `find_package(XXX)` *normally* sets variables like *XXX_LIBRARIES*, *XXX_INCLUDE_DIRS*, find_library(XXX) sets only variable *XXX*. If you want to use `find_package(XXX)`, you need firstly to obtain `FindXXX.cmake` script.

Comment: @Tsyvarev the code was changed to `find_package(XXX)` throws errors see the edit above.

Comment: Why is there an error here and am I on the right track?

Comment: `am I on the right track?` - Yes. If you want to write `FindXXX.cmake` script by yourself, you may find useful [CMake:How To Find Libraries](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries) wiki page. Also, look into CMake documentation about `find_*` commands which are usually used in such scripts. Currently, your `find_path()` call is incorrect: for hint about include file location, *PATH* option should be used. BTW, `sqlpp11-connector-mysql` project has `FindMySql.cmake` script (under `cmake/` directory). You may look into this script as an example.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I managed to get the install of the both packages work and the cpp program is able to find the included files properly as seen in Edit 2. I now have this new problem where it throws the error `undefined reference to `sqlpp::mysql::connection::connection(std::shared_ptr<sqlpp::mysql::con`, Is something wrong with my new CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: Well, you have setup include directories. Next step is to setup *linking with libraries*.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have added my find file and error output, it seems like that the line in my `set(SQLPP11_INCLUDE_DIR /usr/local/include)` is getting the include directory for sqlpp11 which has the generated includes from installing sqlpp11-connector-mysql not from my find file. How am I still not able to find the package/library properly? I put both the github libraries under `/user/local/libs` folder and installed them. The connector install generated some .cmake files under `/user/local/libs/cmake` do I need to link these somehow? Thank you for the help, this has been very frustrating.

Comment: I just looked at the `install_manifest.txt` files for both projects. The sqlpp11 `make install` only generates `.h` and `.cmake` files while the sqlpp11-connector-mysql project generates all `.h` and one `.a` file, does this mean that there is no library associated with the sqlpp11 project and the only one I have to include is from the connector?

Comment: `does this mean that there is no library associated with the sqlpp11 project and the only one I have to include is from the connector?` - Probably, yes. Just try.